# Where can I find a list of SocketErrorCode and NativeErrorCode thrown by SocketException?

Tags: c#, .net, winapi, exception, sockets

A SocketException has a SocketErrorCode and NativeErrorCode.
I would like to find a list where these codes (or the common onces)
are listed so I can respond in proper fasion.

Does anybody know where to find such a list?

Comment: You can press **F12** on the `SocketException` then look at inside `SocketError SocketErrorCode` enum. always you can follow this trick to find more info about any external/internal libraries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MSDN? [SocketError](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketerror.aspx); or from the native ErrorCode, the [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socketexception.errorcode.aspx) states: "For more information about socket error codes, see the Windows Sockets version 2 API error code documentation in MSDN.".

A few searches shows this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740668.aspx).